# Editable combobox in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there any implementation that combines inputbox and combobox in AngularJS. I require a single control  in which i can type text; if it is available in underlying ng-options then it should get selected and if not then what i typed should  be available as text for further action.

Comment: Can i see your implementation.You can use directive?

Comment: I have a requirement which needs to choose IDs from available options; if create a new ID then can enter new ID which can be added with details ...

Comment: Angular seems to lack a proper combobox. If you use an text input with typeahead, then you have to enter at least one character to get the choices to show up -- not even the down key will bring up the list. On the other hand, if you use ui-select, you cannot enter something not on the list.

However perhaps this oversight is because combobox is just a lousy UI component. Don't try to do too much at once - better to create a separate page to add the new choices.

Answer (score 0):

check this: [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)

seems all kind of wheels are available in angular.
i will still try to re-invent some wheel some day, just for fun.

Comment: Got a little lazy ;-) looking for some available solution which i can readily use...